# Can initialization of queue change values?

Tags: c++, queue, radix-sort

Here I have a List which i hope to successfully 'Radix Sort' it.... But I got a problem with my value in the `list`..
It originally contained

> 5 4 1 2 3 10 9 8 8 2

but when I make my queue at the position below, it suddenly changes `list[6]` to `81`, `list[7]` to `0`..

> 5 4 1 2 3 10 81 0 8 2

I don't know why they change and why only the two elements are changed.. PLEASE HELP!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
Class List
    {
        private:
            int n;
            int * list;
        public:
            List(FILE * _input)
            {
                fscanf(_input, "%d", &n);
                list = new int(n);
                for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                {
                    fscanf(_input, "%d", &list[i]);
                }
            }
            void RadixSort()
            {
                int div = 1;
                queue<int> q[10];
                for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
                    {
                        q[(list[j]/div)%10].push(list[j]);
                    }
                    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
                    {
                        int idx=0;
                        while(!q[j].empty())
                        {
                            list[idx++] = q[j].front();
                            q[j].pop();
                        }
                    }
                    div = div*10;
                }
            }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE * input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    List * list = new List(input);
    list->RadixSort();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe UB. Without the code it will be impossible to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I edited my question

Comment: Is it possible that this code is not the code with your problem? It does not compile.

Comment: After fixing the compilation errors I got a segmentation fault. You have problems with memory allocation. Did you debug your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use square brackets instead of parentheses if you want to create an array.
`list = new int(n);` => `list = new int[n];`

- `new Type` creates a new `Type` and calls the default constructor.
- `new Type(some_arguments)` creates a new `Type` and passes `some_arguments` to its constructor.
- `new Type[some_size]` creates a new array of size `some_size` and calls the default constructor on each element.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_and_delete_(C%2B%2B)) povides a simple explanation, for more you can look at [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not clearly described. But many of these sudden changes are caused by bad memory management. For instance it's possible that you didn't allocate memory for the list pointer.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question.. I have allocated memory for the list pointer but it still doesn't works